# How to send email using XAMMP

Tags: php, email, mercury-mta

Here is my code in php to send email:

```
<?php
    $to = 'xyz@xyz.com';
    $subject = 'Customer_Details Report';
    $msg="some message";

    if($result)
    {
        echo 'your email has been sent';
    }
    else
    {
        echo'email not sent';
    }
?>
```

How do I set up mercury in XAMPP to send the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to configure the `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` files correctly.

The `sendmail.ini` file should contain

```
first smtp_server=mail.gmail.com ,
second smtp_port=465 (if not worked try 587),
third auth_username= xxx@gmail.com auth_password=yourpassword
```

after this restart your server.